# Connect to SQL Server Database using MS Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to mass import a lot of tables from a SQL Server Database into MS Access. I have been able to use this code to import a single table, but I want to find a way to import many (not all) tables.

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "ODBC Database", _
"ODBC;Driver={SQL Server};Server=[serverName];Database=[dbName]" _
& ";Trusted_Connection=Yes", acTable, "tableName", "tableName"
```

I'm thinking if I can connect to the database, I can iterate through all the tables that match my criteria and loop through the code above, replacing tableName with each table. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
Dim c As ADODB.connection
Dim r As ADODB.Recordset
Dim connStr As String

connStr = "DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=[serverName];Database=[dbName];Trusted_Connection=yes;"
c.Open connStr
```

This is the error I get.

```
"Object variable or With block variable not set"
```

Anyone have any suggestions on how to approach this?

---

Also on a side note, I have been trying to transfer tables using DSN to connect, but I am not sure how. This is what I have.

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "ODBC Database", _ 
"ODBC;DSN=[DSN File];LANGUAGE=us_english;" _ 
& "DATABASE=[dbName]", acTable, "tableName", "tableName"
```

[DSN File] is a DSN file that I have saved in the same folder as my MS Access file. I think I need to add more info to specify the DSN, since I'm not sure how the code will know where to look for the DSN file. This is the error I am getting. Thanks for any help in advance.

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (#0)
```

Edit: Everything works when I connect without using the DSN. But I'm curious, how would I do it using a DSN file? Thanks

Comment: You need to do `Set c = New ADODB.connection` before you call `c.Open`

Comment: oh wait im a monkey. that fixes everything but the DSN part. thanks